# Winforms combobox has lag populating

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox that is populated when you press a button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> countries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //Dictionary<string, List<State>> stateList=new Dictionary<string,List<State>>();
        HashSet<string> country = new HashSet<string>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("CountryState.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] items = line.Split('\t').ToArray();

            try
            { 
                countries.Add(items[0], items[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                  //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

            country.Add(items[0]);

            if (!stateList.ContainsKey(items[0])) {
               stateList.Add(items[0], new List<State>());
            }

            if (items[2] != "")
            {
               stateList[items[0]].Add(new State(items[2], items[3]));
            }
            if(items[2] !=string.Empty && items[3] !=string.Empty)
                stateCodes.Add(items[2], items[3]);

            }
            comboBox1.DataSource = countries.Keys.ToList();
    }
```

The comboBox1 datasource has at most 234 entries, which doesn't seem too excessive to me (other times I've seen this discussed online its mentioned that a thousand or so entries is excessive).

Comment: Take a look at this line how come your brackets don't line up if(items[2] !=string.Empty && items[3] !=string.Empty)
                stateCodes.Add(items[2], items[3]);

            }

Comment: Looks like you're reading all the lines in that file. How many lines does the file have? What's the size of the file on disk?

Comment: The file being read has like 350 lines

Comment: Also if this is data that can be used again and again why not store the values in a Database and bind the State Codes to one that drop down or consume a webservice ..

Comment: How many lines are in the input file which cause exceptions to be thrown when adding to `countries`?

Comment: how is this code working when you have stateList commented out //Dictionary<string, List<State>> stateList=new Dictionary<string,List<State>>();

Comment: stateList is defined someplace else

Comment: Sorry, there's extra stuff in there that I don't think (but am not sure) is relevant to the issue.

Comment: There's maybe 80 or so lines that cause the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Can you give an example of what or how the data is being stored.. as well perhaps using a Dictionary<string, string> may not be the best option..

Comment: The data being stored is four columns, tab delimited. Countryname, country code, state name, state code (but not all countries have states).

Comment: That's probably not enough to cause noticeable lag but the blanket catch is still bad practice. Check the length of the array and check for duplicate keys instead

Comment: Is it also a problem that I'm reading everything from the file at once, rather than going line by line?

Comment: I think that it would be best to parse that information and store it into a Database.. then run a Query and use something like BindingList on the drop down boxes that way your sql query would select all where whatever column is not empty..

Comment: It will be for larger files, but for this size you should be fine

Comment: Why do you have both country and countries? You only use countries.Keys, which should be equivalent to country

Comment: Sorry, I'm sorta overwhelmed trying to answer all of this and am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)

```
        try
        {
           if (!counties.ContainsKey(items[0)
           {
             countries.Add(items[0], items[1]);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

Comment: I'm needing to make a dictionary out of <countryname, countrycode>. Since you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary, it was the only way I could think of to "cheat"-to read in data that contained multiple keys.

Comment: Hmm...that only contains the first country. EDIT again: Okay, that does work! I didn't step through the debugger all the way! Thanks!